Internal Sever Error 500 when testing with Jest in Express
I am currently making tests for my backend but stuck in only 1 route. And the problem is w
import request from 'supertest';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import app from '../index'; // Assuming you have an Express app instance exported as 'app'
import Trip from '../models/Trip';
import Destination from '../models/Destination';
import debug from 'debug';

describe('Trip Routes', () => {
    // Connect to MongoDB before running tests
    beforeAll(async () => {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        } as any);
    });

    // Clear all collections in the database after each test
    afterEach(async () => {
        await Trip.deleteMany({});
        await Destination.deleteMany({});
    });

    // Disconnect from MongoDB after running tests
    afterAll(async () => {
        await mongoose.disconnect();
    });

    it('should create a new trip', async () => {
        const tripData = {
            name: 'Test Trip',
            description: 'Test Description',
            image: 'image.jpg',
            participants: ['Participant 1', 'Participant 2'],
            date: new Date(),
            destinations: []
        };

        const response = await request(app)
            .post('/trips')
            .send(tripData);

        expect(response.status).toBe(200);
        expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('_id');
        expect(response.body.name).toBe(tripData.name);
    });

   .....

    it('should search trips by name', async () => {
        // Create test trips
        await Trip.create({
            name: 'Test Trip 8',
            description: 'Description 8',
            image: 'image8.jpg',
            participants: ['Participant 8'],
            date: new Date('2024-01-01'),
            destinations: []
        });

        await Trip.create({
            name: 'Another Test Trip',
            description: 'Description 9',
            image: 'image9.jpg',
            participants: ['Participant 9'],
            date: new Date('2024-02-01'),
            destinations: []
        });

        const response = await request(app).get('/trips/search?name=Test');
        debug(response.body);
        expect(response.status).toBe(200);
        expect(response.body.length).toBe(1);
        expect(response.body[0].name).toBe('Test Trip 8');
    });

    it('should search trips by date', async () => {
        const response = await request(app).get('/trips/search?date=2024-02-01');
        expect(response.status).toBe(200);
        expect(response.body.length).toBe(1);
        expect(response.body[0].name).toBe('Another Test Trip');
    });

    it('should search trips by name and date', async () => {
        const response = await request(app).get('/trips/search?name=Test&date=2024-01-01');
        expect(response.status).toBe(200);
        expect(response.body.length).toBe(1);
        expect(response.body[0].name).toBe('Test Trip 8');
    });

});
 

I got problems with the last 3 tests
Errrors
This is my trip router
// Search for trips by name or date
router.get('/search', asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { name, date } = req.query;
    let query = {};
  
    if (name) {
      query = { ...query, name: new RegExp(name as string, 'i') };
    }
  
    if (date) {
      query = { ...query, date: new Date(date as string) };
    }

    console.log('Query:', query); // Logging the query object
  
    const trips = await Trip.find(query);
    res.json(trips);
  }));
export default router;

// src/models/Trip.ts
import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose';

export interface ITrip extends Document {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    image: string;
    participants: string[];
    date: Date;
    destinations: mongoose.Types.ObjectId[];
}

const TripSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String, required: true },
    participants: { type: [String], required: true },
    date: { type: Date, required: true },
    destinations: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Destination' }]
});

export default mongoose.model<ITrip>('Trip', TripSchema);

I am wondering why do I get always 500. I think I did alright. Can you please help me?
I have tried many different ways to make it work. but it always output the same. I am expecting it to pass the test. I don't know either my test or my router is the mistake
